# How do you determine whether the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the .NET 2.0 SDK is installed on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows

How do you determine whether the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the .NET 2.0 SDK is installed on Windows 7?

Comment: Do you want to do this via *code*, or are you just interested in a way you can tell by looking?

Answer (score 1):

Look in registry - path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A

The keys below that would end either in x86 or x64